# FCM Notifications in Xamarin.Forms only working in android emulator

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, visual-studio-2019

I've been trying to implement FCM into my xamarin.forms app in VS2019 and I've been stuck on a problem for a week. Could someone help me out please? It may be something glaringly obvious I've missed...

**Problem: When I port the microsoft xamarin code (see link below) into my xamarin.forms app, the FCM notifications will only display in the android emulator, not on an android physical device.**

I've tried stripping this back into a bare-bones xamarin.forms application, and I'm experiencing exactly the same problem. The code is similar to the microsoft sample solution found at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/firebase-fcmnotifications/

I'll note that compiling the microsoft example does actually work on both the emulated device and also the physical device, both receive and display notifications when the app is minimized.

I've tried this on multiple physical devices, all with the same results - I never get an FCM message on a physical device, compiling exactly the same code and running in the emulated environment - no probs! I get the FCM messages every time.
On the physical devices (4 of them) are a selection running Samsung, MIUI, Huawei and stock android. I have ensured the usual things like enabling Autostart, disabling battery optimisation, ensuring that my app allowed notifications, and ensuring that in app into - that it is registered for FCM notifications and allowing them. (all to no avail).

I've added the appropriate NuGet packages
(Xamarin.Essentials, Xamarin.Firebase.Common, Xamarin.FirebaseIid, Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging, Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base+Basement+Tasks).
I'm not getting any compiler errors or other warnings.

I noticed there was a couple of differences in the OnCreate methods, I'm passing the data for a savedInstanceState and it looks as though in the MS example they're passing a new bundle, but I'm not clear that this would make any difference, and would not explain this behaviour.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.corp.my-fcm-test" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="my-fcm-test">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using myappname.Droid;

using Android.Gms.Common;

using Firebase.Iid;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace my_fcm_test.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "my_fcm_test", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

        const string TAG = "*** *** *** MainActivity";

        internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";
        internal static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
        TextView msgText;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // go through each of the keys in inten.extras and log what they are.
            if (Intent.Extras != null)
            {
                foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
                {
                    var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                    Console.WriteLine(TAG, "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
                }
            }

            CreateNotificationChannel();

            IsPlayServicesAvailable();


            Console.WriteLine(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token);

            FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("news");
            Console.WriteLine(TAG, "Subscribed to remote notifications");



            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }



        public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
        {
            var resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
            {
                if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
                {
                    msgText.Text = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("*** *** *** This device is not supported");
                    Finish();
                }

                return false;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("*** *** *** Google Play Services is available.");
            return true;
        }


        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
                // channel on older versions of Android.
                return;
            }

            var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
            {
                Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
            };

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }


    }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingServices.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using Firebase.Messaging;

using my_fcm_test.Droid;

namespace my-fcm-test.Droid
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TAG, "From: " + message.From);

            var body = message.GetNotification().Body;
            Console.WriteLine(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body);
            SendNotification(body, message.Data);
        }

        void SendNotification(string messageBody, IDictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            foreach (var key in data.Keys)
            {
                intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
            }

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                                      .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
                                      .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                      .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                      .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }


    }
}
```

MyFirebaseIIDService.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using Firebase.Iid;

namespace my-fcm-test.Droid
{

    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
            Console.WriteLine(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }

        void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
        {
            // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        }
    }


}
```

And of course I've included my google-services.json, I'm going to have to assume that file is correct because:

a) I generated a google-services.json file to use with the microsoft xamarin sample, and it worked fine on all devices.

b) I don't change the google-services.json file between doing a debug build and a release build.

- NB I've changed the namespaces for this post.

any help appreciated...

Comment: Did you had any solution to this?

Comment: Nope, turning off code shrinker didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

open Android Project properties, in Android options (Packaging Properties) code shrinker keep it blank. It will work